# Kafka Streams API- filter operator: "ERROR: wrong number of type arguments; required 1"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Stream API to transform a stream.

This is my code:
[image: code]

and this is the error message:
[image: error]

Would anyone know what is causing this error? Thanks

Comment: No picture of code, paste it as text in your post

Comment: Don't return `true/false` based on a boolean expression, directly return boolean expression

Comment: I suggest you use an actual IDE rather than wait for javac to tell you what the error is. Also, why not use lambda functions?